# Architecting a message queue based integration

Tags: architecture, cloud, message-queue, publish-subscribe

Our current legacy system is on-premises. We're planning on migrating our applications to the cloud as a long term goal, but in the interim, we need to integrate this legacy system with our cloud based apps.

**Our goal:** to design an integration that will enable our legacy system to communicate with our new cloud-based applications.

**Our plan:** we will use messaging queues to enable loosely coupled communicating between our legacy system and the cloud.

We're going to have a message broker instance on our legacy system, and another on the cloud. We are eventually going to end up with several different applications on the cloud, all of which will communicate with the legacy system, yet be decoupled from the rest of our apps on the cloud.

**What would be the best way to achieve this?**

Do we:

1. Have each of our cloud apps "connect" to our single broker on the cloud and receive messages in a pub/sub manner?
2. Have dedicated queues for each of our cloud apps, and have our cloud apps read those messages directly off their queue.

I understand that my question is a little high level as it pertains to system design, but at the same time I hope it's also specific enough. Any input or feedback will be welcome.

Comment: Did you find an approach in the end?

Answer (score 0):

I would strongly recommend you to take a step back and strategize your architecture before committing into technical infrastructure decisions:

1. BUSINESS: Identify the different sub-domains ("components") from your legacy application and the new Cloud apps and their relative importance: Core, Support, Generic. Thus you will prioritize what should be migrated from the legacy.
2. TEAM: If you manage more than one team (legacy vs Cloud teams maybe in your case?), ensure the teams are aligned with the sub-domains ([Inverse Conway Maneuver](http://betica.com/blog/2016/06/17/transform-your-organization-with-the-inverse-conway-maneuver/)) so you minimize the collaboration frictions.
3. COUPLING: Define the relationships between the different sub-domains: who's upstream, downstream, what are the interfacing contracts?

THEN you can start to consider the "plumbing" and the different infrastructure options to connect your components based on your technical requirements: synchronous, asynchronous, etc. And back to your original question in the case of asynchronous connectivity: via a message queue broker or not?

These slides explain more in-depth: [Visualizing sociotechnical architectures with Context Maps](https://speakerdeck.com/mploed/visualizing-sociotechnical-architectures-with-context-maps?slide=1).

And if this type of architecture approach resonates with you, have a look at [Domain-Driven Design Starter Modelling Process](https://github.com/ddd-crew/ddd-starter-modelling-process) with many more details.